# $(this).dequeue(); vs next();

Tags: jquery, queue

Is there any difference if I do:

```
$queue.queue(function(next){
   //...
   next();
}).queue(function(next){
   //...
   next();
});
```

versus

```
$queue.queue(function(){
   //...
   $(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
   //...
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Do they do the same thing?

What are the differences and which should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't much difference. `next()` simply calls `.dequeue()` with variables held in a closure ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/queue.js#L28-L30)):

```
var ...,
    next = function () {
        jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
    };
```

I'd say to use `next()` as it just means less you have to do, since it already has what you need for `.dequeue()` -- the elements and queue name (or `type`).

Comment: So why would **anyone** ever use `.dequeue()`? Also the jQuery docs does not really mention `.next()`, they always say to use `.dequeue()`..

Comment: @Neal You still need `.dequeue()` to start cycling through a `.queue()`, especially when using a different queue name other than [the default `"fx"`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/).

Comment: For some reason my `queue` seems to run on its own. I never had to run `dequeue`, maybe I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: `queue` directly is fine, it just gets passed along `this.each(function() { var queue = jQuery.queue( this, 'fx', yourFunc );});` [queue src](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js)

Comment: @Sinetheta I just have `$queue.queue(fn);`

Comment: @Neal Not *wrong*. The `"fx"` queue is just the same queue that the animation timers use, which will call `.dequeue()` for you. http://jsfiddle.net/BSqjs/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski interesting. So all my queues (if I do it the way I have been doing it) won't require a dequeue at all to start. **cool**

Comment: @JonathanLonowski well I get `function (){f.dequeue(a,b)}` when I do `console.log(next);`, but I guess it is the same thing?